How can you generate MCAR, MNAR and MAR missingness pattern in a dataset using python?
For MCAR, it is simply missing completely at random, and using random might work for MCAR.
Example:
reshaped = data.reshape(data.shape[0]*data.shape[1],data.shape[2])
x = reshaped.shape[0]
y = reshaped.shape[1]
for i in range(0,math.ceil(x*y*mdp/100)):
  reshaped[random.randint(0,x-1),random.randint(0,y-1)] = float('nan')


I have looked into several documents, but not exactly I could find simpler version with proper explanation to generation of missing data pattern
